# How to prove the following formula using an indirect proof

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I need to prove that the premise $A \to (B \vee C)$ leads to the conclusion $(A \to B) \vee (A \to C)$. Here's what I have so far.

[image]

From here I'm stuck (and I'm not even sure if this is correct). My idea is to use negation intro by assuming the opposite and coming up with a contradiction. I assumed $A$ which led to $B \vee C$ and, as you can see, I'm trying or elim but the only way I can think of doing this is to use conditional intro and then or intro but that seems to only work for a single subproof. In other words, I can't use the assumption of $B$ to say $A \to B$. This is called an indirect proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to prove that the premise $A \to (B \vee C)$ leads to the conclusion $(A \to B) \vee (A \to C)$. Here's what I have so far. ...

A disjunction is usually proven by reduction to absurdity.   Assume its negation and derive a contradiction.   Typically this involves further assuming the negation of one disjunct aiming to derive the other. $$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{A\to (B\vee C)}{\fitch{\lnot((A\to B)\lor(A\to C))}{\fitch{\lnot (A\to B)}{\fitch A{~\vdots\\C}\\A\to C\\(A\to B)\vee(A\to C)\\\bot}\\\lnot\lnot(A\to B)\\A\to B\\(A\to B)\vee(A\to C)\\\bot}\\\lnot\lnot((A\to B)\vee(A\to C))\\(A\to B)\lor (A\to C)}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is always a *very bad* sign when someone has started a bunch of subproofs without indicating what happens at the end of the subproof.

A proof should always have a *plan* or *outline*, and subproofs provide the skeleton to do so. But again, you need to indicate what you want to do with the subproof, and that involves indicating what you want as the last line of your subproof. You haven't done that for any of the three subproofs you started, which is exactly why you get in trouble, and get see the forest for the trees.

Now, it is clear that with your first subproof you are hoping to do a proof by contradiction. So, start by creating the proper setup for that:

$A \rightarrow (B \lor C)$

$\quad \neg ((A \rightarrow B) \lor (A \rightarrow C))$

$\quad \text{... skip a bunch of lines ...}$

$\quad \bot$

$\neg \neg ((A \rightarrow B) \lor (A \rightarrow C))$

$(A \rightarrow B) \lor (A \rightarrow C)$

Ok, now that we have set that up properly, let's go back inside the subproof, and see how we can derive the contradiction from the premise and the assumption.

Now, it is at this point that you assume $A$.  Why?

Actually, I think I know why, because I have seen it all too often: you are probably thinking "ooh, it would be nice to have $A$, because then I can combine that with the premise! OK, so let's jist assume $A$"

OK, the problem with this kind of thinking is that you end up *assuming* something that you *want* ... which is always a bad ide, as that will often lead to a circular proof. Indeed, suppose you were indeed to combone $A$ with the premise, and get $B \lor C$ ... OK .... now what?! Well, one thing you can do is to then close the subproof and conclude $A \rightarrow (B \lor C)$ .... but note that now you just get the very premise, i.e. You are getting nowhere.

Here is some general advice on subproofs, that goes back to my initial point about having a plan: before starting any subproof, you should already know how you are going to use that subproof, and in particular, what the last line of your subproof should be, and what rule you will apply after the subproof is done.

Ok, let's regroup. There is really no good reason to assume $A$. Ok, but what should you do on line 3? Well, again, if you *had* $A$, you could combine that with the premise, but rather than *assuming* $A$, you could try and make $A$ your new goal. And, to prove $A$, one thing you could do is to assume $\neg A$, and show that that leads to a contradiction.

However, there is a much more straightforward thing to do. The assumption $\neg ((A \rightarrow B) \lor (A \rightarrow C))$ is a negation of a disjunction, and you are probably aware of how by DeMorgan that is equivalent to the conjunction of the negated disjuncts, i.e. to $\neg (A \rightarrow B) \land \neg (A \rightarrow C)$. Now, I suspect you don't have DeMorgan as an inference rule in your specific system, but think about it this way: apprently you should be able to derive both $\neg (A \rightarrow B)$ as well as $\neg (A \rightarrow C)$ from the  Assumption. Now, both of those statements are negations, and you probably know the best strategy to prove negations: Proof bu Contradiction!

OK, so we have another piece of our plan:

$A \rightarrow (B \lor C)$

$\quad \neg ((A \rightarrow B ) \lor (A \rightarrow C))$

$\quad \quad A \rightarrow B$

$\quad \quad \text{skip a few lines...}$

$\quad \quad \bot$

$\quad \neg (A \rightarrow B)$

$\quad \quad (A \rightarrow C)$

$\quad \quad \text{skip a few lines ...}$

$\quad \quad \bot$

$\quad \neg (A\rightarrow C)$

$\quad \text{few lines ...}$

$\quad \bot$

$\neg \neg ((A \rightarrow B) \lor (A \rightarrow C))$

$(A \rightarrow B) \lor (A \rightarrow C)$

OK, see how this is all nicely organized? How you now have an outline, to which you can add details and provide the missing steps at some later point? *That* is what you are supposed to do! That is how you keep your proof, and your very thinking organized. Indeed, the very point of doing formal logic proofs is to teach you that very skill of careful organization!

Now, I am going to leave those details to you, but leave you with one more hint: what is $\neg (A \rightarrow B)$ equivalent to? .... try and derive that, do the same for $\neg (A \rightarrow C)$, and you're pretty much done! Good luck!

Comment: Ok I'm completely stuck at the very end. I have $\neg(A \to B)$ and $\neg(A \to C)$ but I have no idea where to go from here. I know I can use conjunction intro to  bring them together but I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: @JoshSusa OK, remember that $A \rightarrow B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \lor B$, which means that $\neg (A \rightarrow B)$ is equivalent to $\neg (\neg A \lor B)$, and thus to $A \land \neg B$. So, you should be able to derive both $A$ and $\neg B$ from $\neg (A \rightarrow B)$.  HINT: do this using a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Bram: your comment is essentially the same as the hint in my answer to this question. The OP obstinately refuses to tell us what logic  he or she is working in.

Comment: That's possibly a weakness of http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/ which looks like where the OP's screenshot came from: It does allow you to put in empty spaces to be filled in, but it doesn't automatically adjust line numbers below where you insert lines so you would need to readjust the line numbers cited afterwards.  (And by the way, that does have de Morgan rules as "derived rules" cited as "DeM".)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you assume $A \to (B \lor C)$, $\lnot(A \to B)$ and $A$, then you can conclude $B \lor C$ and $\lnot B$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: So if you assume the negation of the conditional then you can use conditional elim to assume the negation of the proposition letter itself?

Comment: From $\lnot (A \to B)$ you can conclude $A \land \lnot B$.

Comment: You said assume $\neg (A \to B)$ as well as $A$. Which subproof do I start with or does that matter?

Comment: So I checked and I'm confused about how you concluded $\neg B$

Comment: If $B$ is true, $A \to B$ is true. The only way to make $\lnot(A \to B)$ true is to have $A$ true and $B$ false.

Comment: Ok but how can I use proof rules to prove that? I can't seem to use any proof rules to prove that $\neg(A \to B)$ will lead to $\neg B$

Comment: You haven't told us exactly what rules you are using. Does this approach make sense for you: assume $\lnot(A \to B)$ and $B$, then you have $A \to B$ (by discharging a non-existent assumption $A$) and then you get false using $\lnot(A \to B)$. So discharging $B$ gives $B \to \mathsf{false}$, i,e., $\lnot B$.

Comment: I'm using a formal proof system for propositional logic. Essentially there are intro and elimination rules. So something like conditional elim would be that we know that $A \to B$ and we know that $A$ is true so it must mean $B$ is true. conditional intro is where you start a sub-proof with the assumption of $A$ and you prove that it will lead to $B$. The basic idea is that if we assume that $A \to (B \vee C)$ is true then if the formula is valid then it must lead to the conclusion which in my case is $(A \to B) \vee (A \ to C)$

Comment: Yes, I guessed that you are using some kind of natural deduction system, but different systems handle connectives like negation and/or falsehood and axioms like the law of the excluded middle in different ways.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what you're saying. If assumed A and then assumed B then could I conclude that $A \to B$ because I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: If you assume $B$, then you can conclude $A \to B$. In natural deduction systems, that follows from discharging a non-existent assumption. When you say "I tried that and it didn't work", I think you are talking about problems you are having with some kind of proof editor. It might help if you tried some simpler stuff first. e.g., try proving $B \to A \to B$. But if you don't tell me what system you are using, I can only speculate.

Comment: The above screenshot is my proof editor. In that editor, on line 6 I wouldn't be able to say $A \to B$. It says that lines 3-5 don't constitute a sub-proof so am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The screenshot is **not** your proof editor, it is a snapshot of its output (and it doesn't give any evidence that you have tried any simpler problems first, like $B \to A \to B$).

Comment: Well it's in the proper proof format is if you're familiar with this proof format then do you think you could tell me what's wrong?

Comment: No. I cannot tell you what is wrong if you are unable to tell me what proof system you are using.

Comment: It's called natural deduction proofs. The screenshot shows the exact format these proofs should be in.

Comment: There are many systems of natural deduction. You aren't giving any clue about the particular system you are using. I am going to vote for your question to be closed due to lack of context. It would be very easy for you to supply that context and I don't understand why you are so reluctant to do so.

Comment: For the love of god please listen to me. I have no idea what it's called. I am desperately trying to figure out what it's called but I have no idea. Everyone just keeps calling it natural deduction proofs for propositional logic. It contains introduction and elimination rules and conjunctions, disjuctions, conditions, biconditions, and equivalence. You can read about it right here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus

Comment: Again, just look at the screenshot. I'm sure you've seen that kind of syntax before when dealing with logic systems. Are you actually saying you've never done a proof that looks like that?

Comment: Surely you know the name of the program you are using.

Comment: I believe it's called  IMS Learning Tool Interoperability

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't really me help me know what natural deduction system you are using. I can only suggest again that you try some simpler problems first and try to find out how to reason about negation in the system.

Comment: I have done many proofs just like this one where I assume the negation of the conclusion and attempt to derive a contradiction. If the opposite of the conclusion causes me to arrive at a contradiction then it must be the conclusion is true. That's exactly what I'm trying to do here but I have absolutely no idea how to do it. I can do the simpler proofs but when I look at this it's just.....nothing. I have nothing. I keep staring at this and I still have absolutely no idea how any of this works. I thought that maybe the assumption of A and the assumption of B would get me $A \to B$ but no.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/) associated with the *forallx* text. There is no rule in this proof checker that allows inference rules for [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).  So it may not be easy to proceed by negating the goal if it contains conditional statements.

The following attempt to complete the proof shows what might happen:

[image]

To discharge the assumption $A$ on line 3, I will likely have to use the law of the excluded middle on $A \lor \lnot A$ which would involve another subproof.

An alternate way to proceed is to negate something equivalent to either the premise or the goal to remove the conditional statements.  For example note that the premise is equivalent to $\lnot A \lor (B \lor C)$. If I negate that I can rewrite it using the following equivalences:

$$\begin{align}
\lnot (\lnot A \lor (B \lor C)) &\equiv \lnot \lnot A \land \lnot (B\lor C)\\
&\equiv A \land \lnot (B\lor C)\\
\end{align}$$

Rather than using the negation of the conclusion, I will use that statement as the assumption and derive a contradiction.  Here is the proof:

[image]

The contradiction was derived on line 6. Now I have to continue from this point and derive the the goal itself. This detour of negating a statement equivalent to the premise (or goal) may make it easier to derive the goal.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/